# ProcessBuilder does not work with maven and jenkins

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, processbuilder

I am trying to execute a command through the windows `cmd` via ProcessBuilder(which is invoked by maven target, which in turn is a jenkins triggered job) but it is not being executed.

Here is my workflow so far.

1. Jenkins I have a job `SomeJob`, which is manually triggered.
2. One of the targets from my maven project is `mvn compile exec:java` and in my `pom.xml` I have http://pastebin.com/SfDsxfJm
3. In the flow of my main class, I have

> ```
> ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder("CMD", "/C", my_executable.exe,sourcefile,destfile);
> builder.start();
> ```

However, when I trigger the jenkins build, it does not throw any error, but the destination files are not generated. All paths are absolute as of now, but still I am having the issue.

If I run the maven command, directly on the slave,

```
mvn -f C:\\myproject\pom.xml mvn compile exec:java
```

Then the files are generated as usual. I am unable to proceed as to how to debug this issue. Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: What is the content of `stdout` and `stderr` of the `Process` instance you get after calling `start`?

Comment: There are no logs printed on jenkins console output when I  print out the stdout and stderr from ProcessBuilder. However, when I execute locally, I see the logs from .exe file that it is executed successfully. Basically .exe file is the one which I built and it is not getting called when I execute it through jenkins flow

Comment: You probably want to call `builder.inheritIO();` before you call builder.start(), so you can see the process's output.

Comment: Also make sure that the process you have started actually completes using `Process#waitFor()`. Exit code will be interesting as well.

Comment: try reading the process input and error stream
`BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader( process.getInputStream()));
  String line;
  while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
   System.out.println(line);
  }
  BufferedReader br1 = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader( process.getErrorStream()));
  String line1=null;
  while ((line1 = br1.readLine()) != null) {
   System.out.println(line);
  }`